# Problem pairing multiple esp32 boards to my android phone with BLE

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, arduino-esp32

When i try to pair multiple esp32 boards to a Android phone (Andriod V13). It’s only allowing to pair one.
When i go to pair another it says ‘An App is needed’ when trying to pair.

I have already have a app designed. It doesnt allow to pair when going onto setting, connection and bluetooth.

Has anybody experienced this problem? If so how did they sort the problem?

Tried to force the esp32 to connect but doesn’t connect.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem when tried to pair esp32 with my smartphone(android v13). It was discovered there is no such problem with android v7 and I assume till v12 too. Looks like it is some kind of protection in android v13. You can reboot smartphone or clear network cache and the problem will disappear for the 1st connection. I'm trying to make bluetooth mouse(HIDdevice) that can transfer data. If I remove ble data transfer logic then the problem will go. But once the smartphone detects the data transfer from device it makes some mark in bluetooth cache and it no longer able to connect.